# How to add a shadow background of a subset of data

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors

I have made a figure and it returns the default color order for the categorical variable.

```
data=data.frame(data,label_1,label_2)

ggplot(data)+
  geom_point(aes(x=X0,y=X1,colour=label_1))+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1')
```

[image]

now i need to How to add a shadow background of a subset of data like motif1 has a shadow background

how to do this

Comment: You're using `scale_fill_manual()` and should be using `scale_color_manual()`

Comment: In addition to @DaveArmstrong's comment, you may find changing the shape of the points can help clarify the issue, i.e. `geom_point(aes(x=X0,y=X1,fill=label_1), shape = 21)`

Answer (score 0):

### Data

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
n = 1000

dat <- 
  data.frame(
    x = unlist(map(c(-5, 1.8, 3.2), ~rnorm(n,.x,sd = .5))),
    y = unlist(map(c(0, -2.5, 4), ~rnorm(n,.x, sd = .5))), 
    label = rep(c("1mot","2mot","3mot"), each = n) ) 

extra <- data.frame(x = c(-5,1.8,3.2), y = c(0,-2.5,4), label = 'extra')
```

#### With `geom_point(..., shape = 21)`

```r
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, fill=label, colour = label), shape = 21, alpha = 0.5, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=label), shape = 21 , data = extra)
```

[image]

#### Without `geom_point(..., shape = 21)`

```r
# We can plot two sets of points, the first being a solid color with slightly bigger size to make the shadows
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, colour=label), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y), colour = 'white', data = extra, size = 2) +  
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=label), data = extra, size = 1)
```

[image]

```r
# The pro of doing this way is that the points are plotted over the shadow
dat_new <- 
  bind_rows(dat,extra)

dat_new %>%
  {
    tmp_dt <- filter(.,label != 'extra') 
    tmp_ex <- filter(., label == 'extra')
    ggplot(tmp_dt,aes(x=x,y=y)) +
      geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y), colour = 'black', size = 3) +
      geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, colour = label),  size = 1.5) +
      geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y), colour = 'black', size = 3, data= tmp_ex) +
      geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, colour = label),  size = 1.5, data = tmp_ex) 
  }
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Edit

#### Shadow behind cluster

```r
# stat_ellipse can be used to drawn a shadow in the cluster with "geom = 'polygon'"

dat_new %>%
  {
    tmp_dt <- filter(.,label != 'extra') 
    tmp_ex <- filter(., label == 'extra')
    tmp_1mot <- filter(., label == '1mot')
    ggplot(tmp_dt,aes(x=x,y=y)) +
      geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y), colour = 'black', size = 3) +
      geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, colour = label),  size = 1.5) +
      geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y), colour = 'black', size = 3, data= tmp_ex) +
      geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, colour = label),  size = 1.5, data = tmp_ex) +
  stat_ellipse(aes(x=x, y=y, color=label),fill = 'gray50', alpha = 0.3, type = 't', level = 0.9999, geom = 'polygon', data = tmp_1mot)
  }
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This not what i need, i mean to add a gray background under a cluster

Comment: We could use `stat_ellipse` for this

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but what if i want to add the shadow behind the random points. It's shape is a belt and it can't be plotted by ellipse